# How to authenticate user with Amazon Cognito Indentity Provider for Xamarin .net

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito

I need sample/tutorial for using CognitoIdentityProvider in mobile Apps with Xamarin DotNet. (Currently in beta and no documentation, but nuget is available)

I'm success creating code for SignUp and Confirm user but struggling how to authenticate user login after successfull sign up confirm.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

In order to authenticate, you would have to call initiateAuth and respondToAuthChallenge with the necessary parameters as part of the Secure Remote Password protocol. You would have to pass USER_SRP_AUTH as the AuthFlow, ClientId and the USERNAME and SRP_A values as a hashmap in the AuthParameters.

You can use our Javascript SDK as reference for an SRP implementation:

https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/master/src/CognitoUser.js#L159